# Array String de IP

Tags: c#, array, mvc, string, arraylist

La cosa es que necesito es hacer un **if** para que si el valor no está dentro del array haga una cosa y si está dentro del array haga otra.

Este es mi código:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var ladoA = new[]
            {
                "1.1.1.0",
                "1.1.1.1",
                "1.1.1.2",
                "1.1.1.3",
                "1.1.1.4",
                "1.1.1.5"
            };
            string ip = IP();
            if (ip != ladoA)
            {
                ViewBag.Mensaje = "No es válido";
            }
            else 
            { 
               ViewBag.Mensaje="Ip Válida";
            }
            return View();
        }

        public string IP() 
        {
            string host = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
            return ip[1].ToString();
        }
```

El problema es que en esta línea: `if (ip != ladoA)` sale lo siguiente:

```
El operador '!=' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'string' y 'string[]'
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: `if (!ladoA.Contains(ip))`...Por otro lado, no es un `ArrayList`, sino un array de `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se podría hacer con el método [`Contains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1) de *Linq*.

```
bool found = ladoA.Contains(ip);
if (!found)
{
   // No se ha encontrado ip en ladoA
}
```

Otra forma sería usando el método [`FirstOrDefault`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1), también de *Linq*. Este método recibe un `Func<TSource, bool>` como parámetro, donde `TSource` es el tipo de objetos de la colección, en tu caso `string`.
Devolverá el primer elemento que cumpla la condición del `Func` y, si ninguno la cumple, devolverá un `default(TSource)`, que en tu caso será un `null`.

```
var found = ladoA.FirstOrDefault(i => i == ip);
if (found is null) 
{
   // No se ha encontrado ip en ladoA
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias, me ha venido de maravilla.